# DNS with subdomain doesn't work properly

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dns

I have a domain name with OVH but i am hosted on a shared server elsewhere (not very important).

I configured my DNS zones on OVH panel to make my domain name pointing on my server.

- .pari-esc.fr A 188.165.201.172
- www.pari-esc.fr A 188.165.201.172
- redmine.pari-esc.fr A 188.165.201.172

**pari-esc.fr** and **www.pari-escfr** are working fine but **redmine.pari-esc.fr** isn't.

On my shared server admin panel, i configured my subdomain :

- Host : redmine
- Domain : pari-esc.fr
- Redirection Type : L
- Path : /redmine/

But when i am trying to access to [redmine.pari-esc.fr](http://redmine.pari-esc.fr) i have an error :

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator....
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

The weird part is when i am trying to access to **[redmine.pari-esc.fr/index.html](http://redmine.pari-esc.fr/index.html)**, its working... so i am a bit lost...
I thought redmine.pari-esc.fr would automatically find index.html and i don't understand why he is not..

I tried to put a .htaccess with a DirectoryIndex index.html but it didn't resolve my problem...
Maybe there is an other way to configure DNS or subdomain and i did it bad ?

So my purpose is : *when i am going to redmine.pari-esc.fr i want to display my index.html located in my /redmine/ directory*

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The DNS settings are looking ok. Check your path in the server config. /sub/ is an absolute path and that is quite likely not correct. It should be something like /var/www/(your web directory)/sub if it's absolute or simply ../sub/ or sub/ if its relative.

Comment: Humm i think if the path was not correct, sub.mydomain.com/index.html shouldn't display me my file, and that display it right :s